# Traffic light system using counter

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop

I designed a traffic light system using 3 bit counter where the counter acts as a timer.So I had set 3 pulses for Red,2 for yellow and 3 for green.
The circuit works fine except when it transition from clock signal 4 ->5 and 6->7.
PS:- I am actually a CSE grad and NOOB in electronics :-)
[image][image]

Comment: The schematic is truncated.

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: Sure, there are six wires going to/coming from nowhere, ie. the schematic is truncated/cropped/incomplete.

Comment: Yeah,I cropped only the output portion. Anyway I solved the problem.

Comment: Why on earth did you do that?

Comment: Do you mean how it blinks off for a moment?

Answer (score 1):

1st define Shortest interval of Yellow in seconds to determine clock frequency for 1 cycle ( or N cycles.)

Your traces are undefined.

Here is **[another](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%202%200.0032%2069.34413510434165%2050%205%2050%0A163%20296%20336%20320%20336%201%2010%200%200%200%200%200%205%200%200%200%200%0AR%20456%20368%20456%20392%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0A152%20336%20312%20336%20272%201%204%200%205%0Aw%20320%20312%20312%20312%200%0Aw%20312%20312%20312%20320%200%0Aw%20328%20312%20328%20320%200%0Aw%20344%20312%20344%20320%200%0Aw%20352%20312%20360%20312%200%0Aw%20360%20312%20360%20320%200%0Aw%20408%20312%20408%20320%200%0Aw%20424%20312%20424%20320%200%0Aw%20400%20312%20392%20312%200%0Aw%20392%20312%20392%20320%200%0Aw%20432%20312%20440%20312%200%0Aw%20440%20312%20440%20320%200%0A152%20416%20312%20416%20272%201%204%205%205%0A162%20480%20160%20528%20160%201%202.4024259%201%200%200%200.01%0A162%20480%20184%20528%20184%201%202.5024259%201%201%200%200.01%0A162%20480%20208%20528%20208%201%203.5024259%200%201%200%200.01%0Aw%20376%20320%20376%20264%200%0A162%20304%20160%20256%20160%201%202.4024259%201%200%200%200.01%0A162%20304%20184%20256%20184%201%202.524259%201%201%200%200.01%0A162%20304%20208%20256%20208%201%203.5024259%200%201%200%200.01%0Aw%20336%20272%20336%20208%200%0Aw%20456%20320%20456%20152%200%0Aw%20456%20184%20480%20184%200%0Aw%20416%20272%20416%20208%200%0Aw%20416%20208%20480%20208%200%0Aw%20416%20168%20416%20208%200%0Aw%20416%20152%20456%20152%200%0Aw%20336%20208%20336%20104%200%0Aw%20360%20160%20304%20160%200%0Aw%20376%20264%20352%20264%200%0Aw%20336%20208%20304%20208%200%0Aw%20352%20264%20352%20184%200%0Aw%20352%20184%20304%20184%200%0Aw%20352%20184%20352%20120%200%0A152%20352%20112%20480%20112%201%202%200%205%0Aw%20336%20104%20352%20104%200%0Aw%20480%20112%20480%20160%200%0Aw%20528%20160%20528%20184%200%0Aw%20528%20184%20528%20208%200%0Aw%20256%20160%20256%20184%200%0Aw%20256%20184%20256%20208%200%0Ar%20528%20208%20528%20264%200%20200%0Ar%20256%20208%20256%20264%200%20200%0Ag%20256%20264%20256%20272%200%0Ag%20528%20264%20528%20272%200%0A152%20416%20160%20360%20160%201%202%205%205%0Ar%20216%20312%20104%20312%200%201000000%0Aw%20216%20352%20296%20352%200%0Aw%20104%20312%20104%20352%202%0Ac%20104%20352%20104%20384%200%200.0000022%202.4960241150897287%0Ag%20104%20384%20104%20400%200%0Aw%20216%20352%20216%20312%202%0Aw%20104%20352%20128%20352%200%0A183%20128%20352%20216%20352%200%200.5%201.66%203.33%0Aw%20456%20152%20456%20184%200%0Ao%2050%2064%200%204110%205%200.00009765625%200%202%2050%203%0Ao%2018%2064%200%204098%205%200.0125%200%202%2018%203%20Green%0Ao%2017%2064%200%204098%202.5%200.00009765625%200%202%2017%203%20Yellow%0Ao%2016%2064%200%204098%202.5%200.0125%200%202%2016%203%20Red%0A)** solution
[image]

Comment: Thanks,but I have no idea what is this 

Comment: Dual traffic lights . What else? Did you the the simulation link?  What did you graduate from, alternative religion?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a glitch happening when going from state 6 to 7 where bit C goes off before bit B come on.

The solution here is using a [gray code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code#Gray_code_counters_and_arithmetic) counter instead of a binary one. That way only a single bit changes at a time.

Comment: Nope.Not working